# Can we have unique API details for AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Can we have an option to specify `API ID` and base URL for `AWS LAMBDA`. Whenever I deploy an `API` to API gateway using swagger I'm getting new `API ID`.

Answer (score 2):

No the API ID is generated on AWS side, but when you deploy your lambda on an existing api-gateway config, you can keep the API (and its ID) and link the deployed lambda on it (in replacement with the old lambda for example)
For this, you need to specify the API-ID (you can retrieve it through the listing of all API configs)

Think of your API-ID as a unique ID, as your invoke URL is:

[https://*API-ID*.execute-api.*REGION*.amazonaws.com/*STAGE*/*PATH*](https://_API-ID_.execute-api._REGION_.amazonaws.com/_STAGE_/_PATH_)

Comment: Is their any way to fix a static Base url including the API key for a set of functions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely take advantage of the 'PutRestApi' functionality which allows you to use swagger and merge/overwrite the new swagger definition on top of an existing RestApi. You'll keep the same RestApi ID in this case.

In the console, you should see the option to `Import API` in the `Actions` menu when you are viewing Resources on an existing API.

Or in the API docs you can find `PutRestApi` or `put-rest-api` for whatever client you're using.